# Getting error while trying to update or delete post

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have a code written for posting and updating data in MongoDB, for delete data and when I want to update something in mongoDB, it posts without problem, but after success I cannot `redirect`.

Main problem is with the update part, since this is not working at all, I only get error:

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/update/undefined 404 (Not Found)

I am using `findByIdAndUpdate()` in routes, here is the code for post item part and update item:

Posting item (router part):

```
    router.post( "/", async( req, res, next ) => {
log.info(
    `Adding new car category - `,
    req.body,
    req.headers
)

try {
    let { title, author, description } = req.body;

    let avto = new Avto({
        title,
        author,
        description
    })

    await avto.save()

    return res.send( { success: true } )
} catch ( ex ) {
    log.error(
        `Error`,
        ex
    )
    return next( {
        msg: "Error while trying to save car category.",
        code: "CAR_SAVE_ERROR",
        status: 403
    } )
}
})
```

Posting item (/src/pages part):

```
    addCar = async() => {
    try {
        let addCar = await axios.post( 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/avto', {
            title: this.state.title,
            description: this.state.description,
            author: this.state.author
        })
        if ( addCar.data.success ) {
            console.log( "Car successfully added!" );
        }
    } catch ( err ) {
        console.log( err )
    }
    }
```

Update item (router part):

```
    router.put('/update/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
log.info(`Updating car `,
req.body,
req.headers)

try {
    Avto.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{$set:req.body}, {upsert:true}, function(err, avto){
        return res.send("Succesfully Updated!");
    })
} catch ( err ) {
    return next( {
        msg: "Error while trying update car.",
        code: "CAR_UPDATE_ERROR",
        status: 403
    })
}
} )
```

Update item (/src/pages part):

```
    updateCar = async() => {
    try {
        let carId = this.props.match.params.id
        let updateCar = await axios.get( `http://127.0.0.1:8080/update/${carId}`, {
            id: this.state.id,
            title: this.state.title,
            description: this.state.description,
            author: this.state.author
        })
        if ( updateCar.data.success ) {
            console.log( "Car successfully updated!" );
        }
    } catch ( err ) {
        console.log( err )
    }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I am a beginner regarding JS.

Comment: you have defined the route with `put` `router.put('/update/:id'` but calling it with `get` `xios.get( 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/update/${carId}` ? also `this.props.match.params.id` is undefined.

Comment: I have changed from get to put, but how you mean this.props.match.params.id is undefined? How should I define it?

Comment: add you react code where you are setting this data in the state.

Comment: But isn't id defined with code: let carId = this.props.match.params.id ??

Comment: carId is defined with this code with an `undefined` value, because `this.props.match.params.id` is undefined so you need to check your `props` object if you are setting this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the save part. It should be like this:

```
router.post( "/avto", async( req, res, next ) => {
log.info(
    'Adding new car category - ',
    req.body,
    req.headers
);
```

Comment: Save part is working fine - I get a log response that I got a successful save. Also in DB is that post inside. Problem is that I want to clear all fields after successful save post.....